# Install Windows 10 via Win7 on new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've thought about building a computer, but it obviously doesn't have an OS preinstalled; a fresh Win10 copy costs about 135€, but couldn't I just buy a Win7/8 copy and upgrade to Windows 10? (I have the feeling I missed something..)

Comment: Sure, [but how much cheaper is Windows 8](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416786)?

Comment: @Arjan As far as I know, Win7 costs ~35-40€ and Win8 ~80-90€

Comment: Aye. As far as I see you could, but take note of what you buy. If you want windows 10 pro you need to start with something else than win7 home. (etc etc).

Comment: @Hennes Yup, I'm aware of that, but I suppose the home-edition is sufficient for me. Anyways, thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a perfectly legitimate workaround, assuming you buy a full retail version of 7 or 8.1 [8 would need updating to 8.1 first]

MS servers are still authenticating Win 7 even after WIn 10 release [& presumably 8 & 8.1 too, though I haven't tested that]

Comment: So for example this one (https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0084DJV9Q/ref=cm_sw_r_awd_CnDXvbQZK44B3) would work?

Comment: That doesn't look like a full retail, it's a Dell OEM.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that; which one would you suggest? (preferably Windows 7)

Comment: idk, I don't speak German ;-) Something in a MS box, with 'retail' in the title

Comment: Oh sorry ;) I just didn't think about that there are different 'versions' for different languages; I'll take a look at it as soon as I get home